Optical beating
I wonder why in the systems where two optical signals are combined in a way they produce the beating, the photodiode or any other type of detector relying on the photon absorption is used. For example,two optical waves with slightly different frequencies (let's say falling into the radio frequency gap) travelling along the same direction result in emergence of the beating wave, which frequency is equal to frequency difference of the initial waves. This new wave is incident on antenna susceptible to radio waves. Why is it impossible to detect this beating signal using only a conductive material if the resultant wave represents a radio-frequency wave?

it is possible with a bolometer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolometer) but it is not an easy thing to do and has very low frequency response.

My question refers to the absence of induced current in the metallic conductor due to RF oscillations caused by optical beating in a way it happens in antennas. Bolometer is used to estimate the amount of radiated power and relies on using of highly absorptive device, but in contrast to microwave antennas it is not specifically adjusted to respond to a particular frequency of emitted wave.

Are you sure it is impossible? If you had two extremely stable polarized lasers at very slightly different wavelengths, you could combine the beams to produce a beam with an RF component. You could detect it with an antenna. Most light sources won't do it.. Optical frequencies are perhaps $10^{14}$ Hz, and RF $10^8$ or so. You would need long coherence times.

I decided to look through some amount of articles and didn't find anything similar to it. All the schemes based on heterodyning of laser radiation anyway use photodetector. I have some doubts whether this antenna would "see" the combined RF component of the electric field, since optical waves which are constituents of the whole oscillation would not propagate inside the conductor due to the skin effect.

@mmesser314 at optical frequencies metals are going to reflect photons.

@PhysicsDave Not if they're on the scale of wavelengths. How is it different from RF? A large metal sheet reflects radio waves, but we make antennas out of metal. It's easy to make metal optical structures: TSMC makes metal lines at 30 nm ("5 nm" process) versus light at 500 nm. Taken to its conclusion, you get optical metamaterials.

We are by no means an expert, but would like to add: consider the problem in the frequency domain. We have two optical frequencies $opt1$ & $opt2$. Our (ideal) spectrum contains only these two frequencies, the beat frequency ($rf_d$ = $opt1$ - $opt2$) is not present under linear combination of $opt1$ & $opt2$. To produce $rf_d$ requires a non-linear process (one example is in a standard photodiode. Conventional passive antenna will not usually do this or at least not at detectable levels?). Correct me if I'm wrong?

@user71659 so far meta materials are refracting/diffracting .... no absorption .... no energy transformation.

@PhysicsDave nope. They’ve been absorbing for more than a decade

@user71659 Ir frequencies are the bottom limit .... not really practical for "optical" if optical typically means visible.

@PhysicsDave The fact is you're wrong about the fundamental physics: Maxwell's equations are scale invariant. A metal antenna at 100 MHz has the same physics as one at 100 µm, you scale it. The two things you worry about are fabrication, which modern chipmaking has partially solved, and skin depth, which is solved up to the middle of the visible with Au.

@user71659 there's a lot of fundamental physics as to why MM won't scale into the visible and then even begin to behave as an antenna ...

If I take a 400.000 000 THz optical beam and and beat it with a 400.000 010 THz optical beam I get a beat frequency of 10 MHz. However, the electric field isn't oscillating at 10 MHz. The time-averaged intensity (where the averaging duration is longer than the period of 400 THz and shorter than the period of 10 MHz) is oscillating at 10 MHz. The electric field will still see peaks and zero crossing appear with a periodicity of approximately 400.000 000 THz.
The direct oscillation of the electric field, not the oscillation of the intensity envelope, is what matters for absorption of electromagnetic waves by receivers such as antennas or photodetectors.

Here we see a 1 Hz and 1.1 Hz signal beating together. We see that the fast oscillations occur at about 1 Hz (actually it's 1.05 Hz, the average frequency of the two) and there is a slow oscillation at 0.1 Hz. If 1 Hz was optical and 0.1 Hz was RF we would see that the electrons in the antenna would be experiencing forces oscillating at 1 Hz, not 0.1 Hz. Sometimes the forces would be stronger, and sometimes weaker, but always at 1 Hz, not 0.1 Hz.
Perhaps you are confusing interference with mixing. Interference is linear process. Interfering two beams gives you a sum of two beams with different frequencies, but the frequencies of the beams are unchanged. This is in contrast to mixing where you use a non-linear element to combine two beams and get beams with new frequencies. If you could somehow mix a 400.000 000 THz beam with a 400.000 010 THz beam you could get a true RF signal at 10 MHz. But this is a very different process from interfering the two beams. Interfering the two beams means spatially overlapping the beams using, e.g., a beam combiner. Mixing two beams requires combining the two beams in a non-linear optic and matching various other special conditions.

I will provide extra information about all of this:
1: The integral of any EM signal, is 0. By this I mean that the displacement of a charge will be 0. Now when you have an actual RF signal, with low frequency and long wavelength, your antenna will displace the electrons a long way and you can measure the voltage created through time, because this is also very slow for the electrons. Now, if you used 2 laser beams as carriers of a 10 MHz beat signal, the displacement of the electrons is done at the center frequency between the two lasers (so, basically laser 1 frequency +5MHz), but only the displacement amplitude is being modulated at 10MHz. The electrons are being "shaken" still at the center frequency, so no capacitor in the world is going to be able to keep with with 100s of THz of frequency, ie, its going to be hard to measure the voltage.

Whoever downvoted mine and PhysicsDave answer (which I think I was referring to) should have at least added some comment on why. Antennas won't work, photodiodes will.

Radio and optical are very different. In a radio waves you have many many photons ... each interacts with free electrons in the metal .... it is possible to have net zero electron flow when a million electrons are sent one way and a million are sent in the opposite direction by 2 opposing/phase radio waves. One could say the photons or radio waves are cancelling but it is not true ... photons never cancel each other ... it's the electron current!  Yes energy is absorbed but there is no signal.
In optical we use photodetectors, we just detect the number of electrons ... not their direction or induced voltage.  All photons are counted and energy is absorbed.  Optical beating is very debatable and misleading ... even controversial.  There are always other elements in the apparatus like beam splitters, slits, lenses that provide "modes" which in turn enable "interferences" that lead to optical frequency dependent observations.
